# How would one formulate large cardinals beyond rank into rank?

Tags: logic, soft-question, set-theory, large-cardinals

Rank into rank cardinals seem to push the limits of consistency, and are stronger than (almost?) every other consistent large cardinal. Despite that, It seems to me, and from a few online discussion posts I've seen, that large cardinals should go on "forever." How would one go beyond rank into rank? Would it require a method other than elementary embeddings? Have any stronger axioms (which have not been found inconsistent) been formulated?

Comment: This is pretty much a question related to the current edge of research in set theory probably so an answer is unlikely to be given soon. Things get interesting even at the "immediate" levels after $\mathbf{I0}$, since it was shown assuming  $\mathbf{DC}$ that the existence of an embedding ${\mathbb{V}_{\lambda+3}\rightarrow\mathbb{V}_{\lambda+3}}$ implies the consistency of ZFC + I0, but for ${\mathbb{V}_{\lambda+2}}$ it does not(see the first  response here for reference https://mathoverflow.net/questions/237031/does-conzf-reinhardt-really-imply-conzfc-i0?noredirect=1&lq=1)